# tmux rotate panes in the sense of turning the splits

Tags: tmux

In tmux there is a command called 'rotate-window', which swivels the panes around numerically. An example could be:

```
┌───┬───┐   ┌───┬───┐
│   │ 2 │   │   │ 3 │
│ 1 ├───┤ → │ 2 ├───┤
│   │ 3 │   │   │ 1 │
└───┴───┘   └───┴───┘
```

However I would like to rotate the panes in the sense of turning the splits like so:

```
┌───┬───┐   ┌───┬─┬─┐
│   │ 2 │   │   │ │ │
│ 1 ├───┤ → │ 1 │2│3│
│   │ 3 │   │   │ │ │
└───┴───┘   └───┴─┴─┘
```

or

```
┌───┬───┐   ┌───────┐
│   │ 2 │   │   1   │
│ 1 ├───┤ → ├───┬───┤
│   │ 3 │   │ 3 │ 2 │
└───┴───┘   └───┴───┘
```

depending on what pane is chosen as the pivot pane and what direction is chosen.

So far what I am using is switching between layouts, but I would prefer being able to rotate like illustrated.
Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure about `tmux`, but in `i3`, you could select window 3 and use `$mod+shift+right` to achieve scenario 1.  You could select window 1 and use `$mod+shift+up`, `$mod+down`, then `$mod+shift+right` to achieve scenario 2.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to emulate in tmux what I can already do in my wm. But being able to do it in a wm does not replace being able to do it in a multiplexer.

Comment: How to convert 2 horizontal panes to vertical panes in Tmux: https://superuser.com/questions/493048/how-to-convert-2-horizontal-panes-to-vertical-panes-in-tmux

Comment: Switch the split style of 2 adjacent panes in Tmux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439294/tmux-switch-the-split-style-of-two-adjacent-panes

Comment: Thank you @NeilG, I was able to use those discussions, to rotate individual panes (example 2 from my question). I can not rotate multiple panes (example 3 from my question), but that is already pretty great, thank you. I am using a keybind to `move-pane -t '.!'` with or without an `-h` flag.